# Have python import library from anaconda instead of /usr/local/lib

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, homebrew, anaconda

I'm using Mac OSX 10.10, and I would like python to import a library from anaconda instead of /usr/local/lib.

The reason for this is that when I was building a package that had an opencv dependency, I was getting opencv related errors when trying to import it. I had originally installed opencv with homebrew (version 2.4.11), but decided to try installing it with anaconda (which installs version 2.4.8). When I built the package and linked it to the anaconda install, everything worked.

However, when I'm running a program with the module, I'm getting a segfault 11 error that I believe is related to opencv. I checked what version of opencv the program was importing and it seemed as though it was importing 2.4.11 (when I ran import cv2).

How can I get it to import anaconda's version without deleting the homebrew installed version. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it easier to use anaconda as default?

Comment: Not in all cases. For example their X11.h files are missing a lot of functions. I'd like to have it import cv2 from anaconda in this case, though.